# Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated - parent key not found

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have many tables in oracle sql develepor. Review table is connected to Book Table.

I already defined a foreign key to connect them each other but there is an error here.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (JSPPROJECTDATABASE.FK_BOOK_ID_BOOK_TABLE) violated - parent key not found
```

How can I fix it?

Here is my screenshot to show foreign key.

[image]

Comment: I saw your picture, but there's no error there, you get a java exception when you git the OK/Apply button?

Comment: The Error ORA-02291 mean you are violating the Foreign Key via an insert or update.  Specifically the value you are inserting into the book_id column of the Review table does not exist in the Book Table.

Comment: @StephenCaggiano I solved the issue by your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please avoid using third party services to show images. If you need to add images, add them to the post by either clicking the image button while editing, or copying the image and clicking CTRL+V, or in any other way pasting it) directly into the post. Third party image services [can break at any time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354950/6296561), and either leave a dead link, or the URLs can be used for malicious purposes.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. Insert images/links using edit functions.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value inserted into the book_id column of the Review table should be in the Book Table.If not, it throws an error like this.